# Конфликт шифрования пароля в связке exim + dovecot + postfixadmin + mysql + roundcube

Tags: postfix, mysql, email, exim

Ситуация такова:

Есть настроенный почтовый сервер.

Ящики создаются через postfixadmin, система авторизации завязана на mysql, для шифрования паролей из-за postfixadmin используется схема MD5-CRYPT, потому что иначе (насколько мне известно) постфиксадмин не умеет.

Однако для авторизации в Roundcube можно использовать либо CRAM-MD5, либо plain.

Есть какие-то обходные пути? Может есть какие-то модули для Rouncube? Или приличные почтовые веб-клиенты, которые понимают md5-crypt?

Comment: А в dovecot-sql.conf такая строка: default_pass_scheme = MD5-CRYPT есть?

Comment: да, конечно.Дело именно в Roundcube. Он делает запрос к давкату и давкат в логе пишет что-то подобное "От меня хотят cram-md5, но у меня есть только md5-crypt. Извините, пароль отдать не могу"

Answer (score 1):

Перерыл всё, что мог. Похоже, в Roundcube только CRAM! У них даже на форуме про MD5-CRYPT ничего нету. Разве что, в исходниках поискать... Но до этого я не добрался. А те, кто делал реально такую связку: http://forum.lissyara.su/viewtopic.php?p=243388 и http://wolandblog.com/page/15/?s=http - на это просто наплевали, и юзали plain. Сам такого не делал, Господь миловал!

Comment: спасибо большое. Жаль, что пароли придется в открытом виде хранить (

Comment: Вам это критично? Тогда зачем именно такая связка? Можно же и по-другому, через stunnel, например!

Answer (score 0):

postfixadmin-2.3.7

config.inc.php:

```
// Encrypt

// In what way do you want the passwords to be crypted?

...

**// dovecot:CRYPT-METHOD = use dovecotpw -s 'CRYPT-METHOD'. Example: dovecot:CRAM-MD5**

$CONF['encrypt'] = 'dovecot:CRAM-MD5';
```

не оно?